# SCSS import relative to an imported stylesheet?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass, zurb-foundation

I've installed `foundation-rails` in my Rails app and run `rails g foundation:install`. The project-specific file(s) (mostly `foundation_and_overrides.scss`) are properly installed. The gem is there and it had no trouble installing, and the dependencies (SASS, Compass) are also there. But I'm getting:

```
Error compiling CSS asset
SASS::SyntaxError: File to import not found or unreadable: global.
```

Originating from:

```
/Users/local/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/foundation-rails-5.0.2.0/vendor/assets/stylesheets/foundation/components/_accordion.scss:1
```

After investigating, I've discovered that `_accordion.scss` was `@import`ed in the main `foundation.scss` file, located two directories up in `stylesheets/`:

```
@import 'foundation/components/accordion'
```

The "missing" file, `_global.scss`, meanwhile, is in that same directory. If I then change the `@import` code in `_accordion.scss` from `@import 'global'` to `@import 'foundation/components/accordion'`, it clears and moves on to the next error (there are a lot of sub-imports here).

It's clear that what's happening is **SASS is looking for `_global.scss` relative to the top stylesheet, `foundation.scss`**, and not relative to the imported stylesheet asking for it (`_accordion.scss`).

I can't imagine this is a bug in Foundation/Foundation-Rails – this gem wouldn't work for anyone – and I don't want to modify the gem's contents myself.

So my question: do I have to change some SASS settings to allow `@import` relative to an imported stylesheet? I don't want to modify this gem to make it work (I'd like to allow for future updates to the gem).

### Edit

Clarification of directory structure within the gem's `vendor/assets/stylesheets` directory:

```
foundation.scss
foundation/components/_accordion.scss
foundation/components/_global.scss
```

### Edit 2

You can actually see the gem's code and structure on [github](https://github.com/zurb/foundation-rails/tree/master/vendor/assets/stylesheets)

### Edit 3

Thought I'd solved the problem, but I didn't: changing from an `@import` to a `=require` got rid of the errors, and included Foundation's CSS. But `require` does not import the SCSS functionality - variables, mixins - that Foundation provides. There's no way to change global values this way, or to retrieve them or the mixins from the main stylesheet or other `@import`ed stylesheets.

Comment: Could you clarify where the files in question live, which files are importing which and what their import statements look like?  It sounds like there's `foundation/_global.scss` and `foundation/components/_accordion.scss`.  I would expect an error if accordion is importing global via `@import "global";`, but if the path to global is actually `foundation/components/_global.scss` then it should work as you expect.

Comment: The latter is correct. See edit.

Comment: This looks like a bug to me, but I couldn't tell you which project you would send your bug report to.  I use Sass/Compass outside of Rails/Ruby projects, so Foundation looks like it is authored correctly.  You don't by chance have any stray files floating around that have a similar path as the Foundation files, do you?

Comment: I'm not sure how much of a bug it is – when I've used SASS independently, I've encountered the same behavior: imported files need to assume the master file's directory for any relative imports of their own. But I can't imagine the people who make Foundation have just forgotten that and broken this gem for everyone. The Foundation-Rails git doesn't have an "issues" button, either, which is where I'd probably submit this.

Comment: BTW, Compass does imports the same way:  https://github.com/chriseppstein/compass/blob/stable/frameworks/compass/stylesheets/compass/css3/_box-shadow.scss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like Foundation [thinks](https://github.com/zurb/foundation/issues/3855#issuecomment-30372252) this is the best possible solution:

Manually add Foundation's stylesheet subdirectories (each of them) to SASS's `:load_paths` in the main block of `application.rb`:

```ruby
config.sass.load_paths += [
  "#{Gem.loaded_specs['foundation-rails'].full_gem_path}/vendor/assets/stylesheets/foundation/components",
  "#{Gem.loaded_specs['foundation-rails'].full_gem_path}/vendor/assets/stylesheets/foundation/"
]
```